# How do I interpret this delta expression?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to understand the following equation:

I know that  is delta and that it implies a difference between something. My current guess is that y is the delta between x and a * b, but my knowledge is limited so it's just a guess.

I know [] sometimes can be used instead of (), but if I was to interpret [] as () in this example, that would translate to:
    y =  *  ∗

I'd be very happy if someone could help me interpret the equation.

Best regards!

Edit:
The full equation is as follows:

```
CL_δ = (_+_)/ ∗ [_ ∗ _]
```

CL_δ is the coefficient of lift due to elevator deflection. (aerodynamics)

Comment: Could you give some context in which this specific equation occured?

Comment: where did you get the expression from?

Comment: The symbols $\delta$, $[\phantom{r}]$, and $*$ all are used differently in different contexts.

Comment: The full equation is as follows:

    CL_δ = (_+_)/ ∗ [_ ∗ _]

CL_δ is the coefficient of lift due to elevator deflection. (aerodynamics)

Comment: @johnor999 You should add that equation to the body of your question.

Comment: Added it to the body of my question.

Comment: $\delta_e$ is the deflection of the *elevator angle*.

Comment: I think that this quantity is multiplied by $[ \ldots ]$ and that there is nothing misterious in the use of square brackets. See [here](http://people.clarkson.edu/~pmarzocc/AE430/AE-430-6.pdf).

Comment: Yes δ is the deflection angle, but why use [ ]?